# java.io.FileNotFoundException: hi.txt (The system cannot find the file specified) at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)

Tags: java, windows-10, ioexception, fileoutputstream

So basically I am stuck compiling this simple code that creates a new .txt file and write something into it. Don't know how to deal with this **The system cannot find the file specified** issue.

Here is my code :

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class CreateANewFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("hi.txt");
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        FileWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write("null");
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("done!! check if the file has created or not.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is error:

```
   java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1024)
        at CreateANewFile.main(CreateANewFile.java:10)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: hi.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:292)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:185)
        at java.base/java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:96)
        at CreateANewFile.main(CreateANewFile.java:17)
```

So basically, JVM is not being allowed to create or write into any file.

I have cross checked that all of my environment variables are having correct path.

What is going wrong ??
How to solve the issue ?

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: What 'access denied' issue? This is a 'cannot find the file specified' issue. Normally when you get this error on an output file it means the target *directory* doesn't exist. Is this the real code? NB the `File.isFile()` and `File.createNewFile()` calls are not only redundant here, they are worse, because you are forcing the system to delete that file and create a new one when the `FileWriter` is constructed.

Comment: @user207421 yeah, it's a "cannot find the file specified' issue. I am trying to create a file into the current directory. So the target directory is basically the current  directory. That means the target directory do exists.  `file.isFile()` is to check if the file with the same name is already exist or not. If it presents we don't need to create a new one, otherwise `file.createNewFile()` will create a new file with the given name. Now `writer.write()` is writing into that file. I am not forcing my system to delete that file. If any piece of code does so. That is completely unintensional.

Comment: @user207421 I have my own java library, through which I make .txt file with the same of the my .java files, that contains all the testcases that may require for that particular java programs later. So I don't need to put testcases again and again. These are commonly used in competitive programming world. A personal library that creates a new file with the same name to store the testcases, so we can test the codes later on with the same testcases. I am using this piece of code from last six months. I don't know what has happened my pc got updated this code is showing errors. Please help.

Comment: What @user207421 is saying is that `FileWriter()` will create the file.  You don't want or need to create the file ahead of time.  It should work ok though.

Comment: @CryptoFool you wanna say that removing
`file.isFile()` and `file.createNewFile()`  will improve my code ?

Comment: Though there are some improvements needed in code as per above comments, you might want to try to run this program in a different directory.

Comment: @Smile I have tried, but result  is same.

Comment: @user207421 I tried to run my code commenting the unnecessary section. But still it is not solving the main purpose.

Comment: @Smile That is not only what he wants to say, it is what he said, and it is also what I said in the first place.

Comment: The call to `file.createNewFile()` should have created the file, correct? So can you double check (outside your program) that the file is actually there? What happens if you directly pass `"hi.txt"` to the `FileWriter` constructor? Does this raise the same error?

Comment: @DanielJunglas `"hi.txt"` is not present currently inside of the current directory. I tried passing `"hi.txt"` to the `FileWriter` constructor. Unfourtunately it is raising the same error.

Even `file.createNewFile()` is giving the same error.

Comment: @DanielJunglas this time error is not exactly same.
  `java.io.IOException: Access is denied
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:348)  
        `
This is what it is showing. **ACCESS IS DENIED.**

Comment: "Access denied" means that you don't have permission to create files in that particular directory. You may double check what directory you are trying to create the file in (print out `file.getAbsolutePath()`) and/or you may want to create the file an absolute path and specify a directory for which you have write permission.

Comment: I am using this piece of code for my day to day use. I was working fine. From last few days I am having the issue. So I am worried if there's **any virus into my system or some updates in windows or vscode,** that is making the mess.  @DanielJunglas Can it be the reason behind the problem ? Because this code was working fine before.